# Fuzzy clustering using unsupervised dimensionality reduction

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

An unsupervised dimensionality reduction algorithm is taking as input a matrix NxC1 where N is the number of input vectors and C1 is the number of components for each vector (the dimensionality of the vector). As a result, it returns a new matrix NxC2 (C2 < C1) where each vector has a lower number of component.

A fuzzy clustering algorithm is taking as input a matrix N*C1 where N, here again, is the number of input vectors and C1 is the number of components for each vector. As a result, it returns a new matrix NxC2 (C2 usually lower than C1) where each component of each vector is indicating the degree to which the vector belongs to the corresponding cluster.

I noticed that input and output of both classes of algorithms are the same in structure, only the interpretation of the results changes. Moreover, there no fuzzy clustering implementation in scikit-learn, hence the following question:

Does it make sense to use a **dimensionality reduction** algorithm to perform **fuzzy clustering**? 
For instance, is it a non-sense to apply [FeatureAgglomeration](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.FeatureAgglomeration.html#sklearn.cluster.FeatureAgglomeration) or [TruncatedSVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) to a dataset built from TF-IDF vectors extracted from textual data, and interpret the results as a fuzzy clustering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some sense, sure. It kind of depends on how you want to use the results downstream.

Consider SVD truncation or excluding principal components. We have projected into a new, variance-preserving space with essentially few other restrictions on the structure of the new manifold. The new coordinate representations of the original data points could have large negative numbers for some elements, which is a little weird. But one could shift and rescale the data without much difficulty.

One could then interpret each dimension as a cluster membership weight. But consider a common use for fuzzy clustering, which is to generate a hard clustering. Notice how easy this is with fuzzy cluster weights (e.g. just take the max). Consider a set of points in the new dimensionally-reduced space, say <0,0,1>,<0,1,0>,<0,100,101>,<5,100,99>. A fuzzy clustering would given something like {p1,p2}, {p3,p4} if thresholded, but if we took the max here (i.e. treat the dimensionally reduced axes as membership, we get {p1,p3},{p2,p4}, for k=2, for instance. Of course, one could use a better algorithm than max to derive hard memberships (say by looking at pairwise distances, which would work for my example); such algorithms are called, well, clustering algorithms.

Of course, different dimensionality reduction algorithms may work better or worse for this (e.g. MDS which focuses on preserving distances between data points rather than variances is more naturally cluster-like). But fundamentally, many dimensionality reduction algorithms implicitly preserve data about the underlying manifold that the data lie on, whereas fuzzy cluster vectors only hold information about the relations between data points (which may or may not implicitly encode that other information).

Overall, the purpose is a little different. Clustering is designed to find groups of similar data. Feature selection and dimensionality reduction are designed to reduce the noise and/or redundancy of the data by changing the embedding space. Often we use the latter to help with the former.